# Static and crackling in my HDMI audio?

Tags: 13.04, sound, ati, hdmi, hybrid-graphics

So, I managed to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04. In Ubuntu 13.04, I installed the drivers for my graphics card(AMD HD Radeon 7700 Series, I'm pretty sure it's a 7790 one and Intel HD Graphics 4600 for Motherboard, but this shouldn't be necessary, considering that it's not the motherboard where I have connected the HDMI) for HDMI. I went to System Settings, and then to Sound, selected the HDMI sound option. Now, whenever I play anything that has sound, the audio has static and crackling. It does not play correctly. I tried searching, but all I find is questions in which the HDMI audio is simply not recognized and not playing.

Comment: Do you have HDMI audio set for Windows as well? Is the HDMI cable you're using connected to your GPU or motherboard? There is a good chance you are picking up on interference from your motherboard, which causes the crackling. I have a similar problem myself, and have to route my audio through my keyboard to prevent it.

Comment: I do have HDMI audio for Windows as well, and there are no such problems. And the HDMI cable is connected to the GPU.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I finally found a solution to my problem randomly.

```
sudo pico /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

look for

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

and add `tsched=0`

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

This simple modification fixed all the sound crackling and static on my PC, in Google Chrome, chromium, HTML5 videos, etc etc

Comment: I did this, and after a reboot, the static was gone and the crackling was reduced a lot. Now using HDMI is actually enjoyable. Thanks a lot. I do hope this will work with 14.04 when I upgrade(It should work, logically. And I'm going to wait for drivers specifically for 14.04 before upgrading, so we could at least be sure that drivers are not at fault(?)).

Comment: This fixed it for me, too! Can you tell us what this has changed? I'm curious if this may affect something that will give me trouble later on.

Comment: It turns off time based audio scheduling. Apparently some people have glitches with it turned on and for others it works better when turned off :/

Comment: This resolve the noisy and crackle hdmi sound with a radeon x290, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this fix does not work in 16.10

Comment: Worked for me in elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Comment: I can't believe this fixed the problem for me in Ubuntu *18.10*.

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 18.04 / bionic on a Hades Canyon NUC.

Comment: Worked in Pop_OS! 20.04.

Comment: it seems like this worked on Ubuntu 20.10 with Asus monitor speakers. It's been about a week without the noise for me. The crackling noise would appear some time after the reboot, probably after the display went to sleep mode.

Comment: I can confirm it worked for Ubuntu 21.04 with Dell monitors HDMI -> 3mm jack

Comment: This is still necessary in 2021, with ubuntu 21.10 and a Lenovo display. Remarkable that it's not a default thing 7+ years later!

Comment: Is 2022 and this fixed my noise audio issue on Debian 11, thanks

Comment: lifesaver! fixed on Debian GNU/Linux 11 bullseye (x86-64)

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 22.04.3 on "UM773 Lite" mini pc. How is this still not fixed? Does Ubuntu not have a bug tracker for this basic stuff?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with a AMD 6400 and Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 7):

I have a ATI R7 260x, the HDMI audio problem was solved when I've had trying two different workarounds together. It's working as designed now. (on Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit)

Follow the steps below:

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
2. `sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`
3. Replace the line

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect
   ```

   with

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
   ```

   and save file.
4. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
5. Insert `options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0` at the end
   of the file.
6. Reboot the PC

Comment: Now the sound is perfect, thanks. My video card is also a R7 260x

Comment: This fixed the static issue for my onboard Intel audio device in Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. Based on the accepted answer I did up to step 3 with no help. For me, 4-6 made all the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I've had crackling and static as well and I solved it by first muting microphone input, and secondly changing my sound to 7.1 surround (even though I only have 2 speakers).

Comment: Well, I don't have any microphone, and I don't have an option to change HDMI to 7.1 surround. I can do that with the other ones, though. But then I won't have sound at all.

Answer (score 0):

In case others run into this issue, I've had this come up when installing pipelight on Ubuntu 14.04 with the AMD Catalyst 14.6 drivers using an A10-7800 APU.

My only solution was to remove pipelight, but I had not run into the solution above. It's quite possible pipelight messes something up that this solution fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Ubuntu 20.04; the above solution didn't help.
It was due to the bug in PulseAudio, as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1585084 
The solution that worked for me was:
Install alsa-tools-gui 
Run hdajackretask 
Override "Green Headphone, Front side" to "Not connected" 
Override "Pink Mic, Front side" to "Headphone" 
Click "Apply now" 
Click "Install boot override" to make this permanent 
From now on, just plug your headphones in the front microphone jack instead of the front headphone jack...

Answer (score 0):

I had bad and cheap headset cable splitter. It split headset cable into mic and audio, but it also caused static noise when i moved mouse. Also i changed my headphones. Before i had hyperx cloud X but now i have Sennheiser GSP 300
No problem with the OS.