# HDMI Audio crackling only in Google Chrome

Tags: sound, ati, google-chrome, hdmi, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and it's awesome. I use an HDMI cable: video and audio work flawlessly, except on Chrome 64bit (not chromium). Unfortunately, the audio crackles a lot. This happens both with flash videos as well as html 5 ones, so I guess it's not pepper related. Any suggestion? Ubuntu runs on a machine with AMD APU E-450 with open drivers.
Thank you guys! :D

Comment: In case any one comes along. These were effective at solve the issue for me as of 2014-05-28, albeit on Fedora 20. http://askubuntu.com/questions/405071/static-and-crackling-in-my-hdmi-audio
http://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-logout

Answer (score -1):

In a terminal window

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

look for

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

and add **tsched=0**

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```