# Ubuntu 16.10 HDMI Sound Crackling

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

After updating to Ubuntu 16.10, sound playback via HDMI was accompanied with a very bad crackling sound. I've tried various old remedies:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 Pulseaudio in HDMI sound crackling](https://askubuntu.com/q/497887/68420)
- [Static and crackling in my HDMI audio?](https://askubuntu.com/q/405071/68420)
- [Sound in 14.04 is crackling, popping, skipping and echoing](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230750))

None of them works for 16.10.

I ended up re-installing Ubuntu 16.10 from scratch. This fixed the problem. But, after running updates on the system, the crackling noise was back.

If you play the test sounds (through sound settings), then they play perfectly, but if you play any music, in any format, then it does not play.

This problem has been an intermittent problem with Ubuntu for years. For now I've given up and use my internal speakers. Any help will be highly appreciated.

The machine is a Dell XPS 15 9550.

Comment: It must be something specific to the model. I've been using HDMI for many years with dozens of different hardware, Intel, Nvidia and AMD, and never had such issue.

Comment: Maybe, but it works after a fresh install and then breaks after update. So it's a system issue of sorts. It was fine on 16.04